# How can I override panels_everywhere with a tpl?

Tags: theming, panels

I have a site which use panels_everywhere but I want to create a tpl file which contains only the node without any pane for an iframe purpose.

I want to make a condition that if the domain alias is alias.example.com then use a specific tpl witch prints only the node itself without panes. How can I do it?

---

Actually I find a little solution but still have a problem.
The solution I found is this:

```
function Mymodule_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars) {
  global $base_root;
  $domain = $base_root;
  if ($domain == 'iframe.xxx.org' && arg(0) == 'node') {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_view(node_load($nid));
    $vars['node_content'] = $node;

    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__iframe';
  }
}
```

and in the tpl I wrote:

```
print drupal_render($node_content);
```

But the node is rendered 5 times on the page for every pane.

Any solution?

Comment: I wrote my comment as an answer because the code.

Comment: It should have been an edit for your own question, since you are still asking if there are other solutions.